# how keep keyboard after a dialog dismiss when ok button pressed ? in android

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard, dismiss

Keypad is showing in the screen . and show dialog . when I clicked OK Button in dialog, keypad is hide.

```
public void setButton(~)
{
 dialog.dismiss();
}
```

I think dismiss() is include a problem.

How I keep keypad after a dialog closed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..Add this after dialog.dismiss();

InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Here, editText is your EditText instance. Change it accordingly.

---

Add this to your `Activity` tag in your androidmanifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Comment: I want when dialog dismiss